# Is there any Media Centre software for a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, media-center, media-center-extender

I am thinking about getting a Mac Mini (mainly because of it's form factor) and a 24" iMac. I wish to using both of them as home media centres. (please don't ask why I am getting two.. it's complicated).

Anyways, is it possible to setup either Mac to be a media centre and then stream the data over the wire to a dumb terminal?

i'm sorta thinking of how an xbox can be a media centre extender and a pc can be the main media centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides XBMC you also have [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/), the source code is based on the XBMC Media Center code. I use Plex and it works great, I think it got a better UI than XBMC.

Comment: Plex is excellent -- the in-app plug-in system in particular is fabulous. Makes it very easy to find and install plugins to watch online video.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution :) if not Plex, then XBMC.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify that you were needed TV tuner or DVR functionality, I believe [Front Row](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Row_(software)) (which comes installed on every Mac) meets your needs.

Comment: so this would stream an HD movie (read: avi, qt, etc) from the mac-mini to some other device (eg. xbox, pc, macbook pro, etc). ??

Also, i was thinking of getting an EyeTV....

Answer (score 3):

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) is a free open source media centre for Mac, Linux and Windows. It works well. I use it on my Mac to view exsiting Media Centre streams and when on the road to stream to others with very little problems.

Comment: kewl :) does xbmc allow for streaming to extenders?

Comment: Yes it does. I stream to my X-Box and to my Vista Extenders. Not sure about others though.

Answer (score 1):

Check,

- MacWorld: [**My multimedia Mac mini**](http://www.macworld.com/article/51113/2006/05/multimediamini.html)
- MacWorld: [**Mac mini media center: Configuring Front Row**](http://www.macworld.com/article/140088/2009/04/macmini_mediacenter_frontrow.html)
- [**The Ultimate Mac Mini HTPC – Part 1: Media Center Software**](http://www.gamaze.com/blog/2009/03/the-ultimate-mac-mini-htpc-%E2%80%93-part-1-media-center-software/)

  - Followed up with [**Part 2: Installing MediaPortal using Apple Boot Camp**](http://www.gamaze.com/blog/2009/03/the-ultimate-mac-mini-htpc-part-2-installing-mediaportal-using-apple-boot-camp/#more-97)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/homepage/). It's free and works on Mac, Windows, and a variety of set-top boxes.

Comment: Boxee is built on top of XBMC.